# SP 2013 How do I return all fields from a list AND get the User/Title property in the same call?

Tags: 2013, user-accounts

I am wanting to return all the column AND User/Title instead of User/ID...is there a way to accomplish this without making 2 ajax calls?

Comment: If you at using REST then try $expand clause

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured this out on my own...had to use:

```
...blah/items?$select=User/Title,*&$filter=(MyfilterOptions)&expand=User/Id
```